# React-Native: Get cached images by URL

Tags: caching, react-native

If I put an image in a `/images` folder in my React Native project's root folder, I can access it in the debugger with `http://localhost:8081/assets/images/myimage.jpg`;

I'm using react-native-fs to cache images downloaded from the web, and save them to a location like this: `/Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/7[UUID]/Library/Caches/myimage.jpg` (on the simulator).

Would it be somehow possible to serve them so that they are accessible by accessing an endpoint on `http://localhost:8081`?

My use case: I'm trying to load an image inside a WebView:

```
<WebView
  source={{ html: `<img src="http://localhost:8081/assets/images/myimage.jpg" />` }}
/>
```

The above code works, but I wish to load cached images.

This doesn't work:

```
<WebView
  source={{ html: `<img src="file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/[UUID]/data/Containers/Data/Application/7[UUID]/Library/Caches/myimage.jpg" />` }}
/>
```

Comment: if you know the local paths of the images you should be able to `require` them I think. Also as far as I know images with remote urls cached by default I think. Next time you use them they will be served from cache. At least to my knowledge. [`source` prop](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#source) has some information about cache

Comment: Using this you can fire up a server on your phone, which could server the images on localhost https://github.com/futurepress/react-native-static-server. However, when you have the URI you can access the photos without a server. Depends on your usecase!